# .NET ViewState Decoder

Tags: .net, viewstate

Is there any viewstate decoder that really works on .net 4?

I tried Onion's and several other online decoders. There was also an add-in for firefox but that is not compatible with ff4.

I get this error no matter what.

"There was an error decoding the viewstate string. The serialized data is invalid"

I have explicitely set ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableViewStateMAC="false" in my page. Still the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Figured out this does not work in pages where there are telerik controls.

Comment: Why not? It should work regardless of what controls are being used.

Comment: Im having the same problem but it seems to happen when i hit a viewstate of 50kb no idea whats happening tho :/

Comment: The name of the class that responsible for serializing/deserializing view state is System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.  Why dont you just new up a new instance and call its deserialize method

Comment: In Understanding ASP.NET View State on MSDN there is an example on how to parse view state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx Note that this will likely give you the same result that you have already gotten where it can't be parsed.  Are you using View State Compression?  Is that what is preventing you from parsing View State: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/compression.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following

http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx

OR one for fiddler

http://www.binaryfortress.com/aspnet-viewstate-helper-fiddler/
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons